# Importing custom CSS into joomla

Tags: php, css, joomla

I've created a custom template for Joomla and in my CSS I've got a number of style sheets that activate at a certain pixel dimension, like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:761px) and (max-width:1080px)" href="css/720.css">`

Now if I'm to transfer it to Joomla under the PHP for the template I'd write it like:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/720.css');
```

But the issue I'm having is how to I add the 'media' tags to the PHP, otherwise the style sheet will just activate regardless, not under its correct dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet

```
void addStyleSheet( $url, $type, $media, $attribs )
```

You don't need the type setting so you set that to `null` then set the `$media` variable to the value that you would put in that attribute. For example

```
$doc->addStyleSheet(
    'templates/' . $this->template . '/css/720.css',
    null,
    '(min-width:761px) and (max-width:1080px)'
);
```

Comment: Yes I did see that page, but unfortunatly I dont know how to add '$media' as syntax into the PHP, sorry PHP is not a language I use often.